# can't bring the yahoo finance data

Tags: pandas, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I runing this code (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baCAFPHb1o4)

it keep saying error message -->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/yahoofinance/ATPQ6.py", line 50, in <module>
    get_data_from_yahoo()
  File "/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/yahoofinance/ATPQ6.py", line 44, in get_data_from_yahoo
    df = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", start, end)
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 116, in DataReader
    session=session).read()
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py", line 76, in read
    df = super(YahooDailyReader, self).read()
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 155, in read
    df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 74, in _read_one_data
    out = self._read_url_as_StringIO(url, params=params)
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 85, in _read_url_as_StringIO
    response = self._get_response(url, params=params)
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 120, in _get_response
    raise RemoteDataError('Unable to read URL: {0}'.format(url))
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=BRK.B&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=11&e=31&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv
```

how can I fix this error?
please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question appropriately.

Comment: This is probably related: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34249/does-yahoo-google-no-longer-support-web-scraping-of-forex-data